# Spark job `Container killed on request. Exit code is 137` on Dataproc 2.0

Tags: apache-spark, google-cloud-dataproc

My Spark job on Dataproc 2.0 failed. In the driver log, there were many

```
ExecutorLostFailure (executor 45 exited caused by one of the running tasks)
Reason: Container from a bad node: ... Container killed on request. Exit code is 137
```

and

```
23/11/25 10:38:30 ERROR org.apache.spark.network.server.TransportRequestHandler: Error while invoking RpcHandler#receive() for one-way message.
org.apache.spark.SparkException: Could not find CoarseGrainedScheduler.
        at org.apache.spark.rpc.netty.Dispatcher.postMessage(Dispatcher.scala:176)
        at org.apache.spark.rpc.netty.Dispatcher.postOneWayMessage(Dispatcher.scala:150)
```

What could be the possible causes? How do I fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The exception `org.apache.spark.SparkException: Could not find CoarseGrainedScheduler` usually indicates the Spark executor failed or was terminated unexpectedly, and the error `Container killed on request. Exit code is 137` usually indicates the **executor YARN container was killed by Earlyoom** (which is available in 2.0+).

When **the worker node as a whole is under memory pressure**, Earlyoom will be triggered to select and kill processes to release memory to avoid the node to become unhealthy, and YARN containers are often selected. It can be confirmed in `/var/log/earlyoom.log` or in Cloud Logging with

```
resource.type="cloud_dataproc_cluster"
resource.labels.cluster_name=...
resource.labels.cluster_uuid=...
earlyoom
```

You might see logs like

`process is killed due to memory pressure. /usr/lib/jvm/.../java ... org.apache.spark.executor.YarnCoarseGrainedExecutorBackend`.

In this case, you need to reduce memory pressure for the node, either reduce `yarn.nodemanager.resource.memory-mb` so there are more space left for other processes, or increase the worker node memory size.

Note that `Container killed on request. Exit code is 137` is usually NOT an indicator of OOM with the container itself. If the container itself is OOM, there should be errors like `Container killed by YARN for exceeding memory limits. 10.4 GB of 10.4 GB physical memory used`. In this case, you might want to consider increasing the spark executor memory and/or memoryOverhead.